# Is everything staged on Discovery channel?

Tags: television

Sometime ago a question featured on [travel.se](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) about [Mythbusters' duct tape island](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9263/how-to-get-to-mythbusters-duct-tape-island). The footage of the island came from a database and when the guys were running on a so called "deserted island" they were actually meters away from a resort in Hawaii.

More recently I watched an episode of "[Airplane Repo](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/airplane-repo)", where suddenly the pilot ran out of fuel, indicated by the "E" on the compass. So a Repo pilot reads east as empty, yeah right.

Then you always have the "extremely dangerous" decent of [Bear Grylls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_Grylls), only to be caught up by a new camera man below. He gives the impression he is alone.

After finding out more, similar flaws, on Discovery Channel, I am now really wondering if there is anything for real on Discovery Channel, or is it more simply fictional entertainment?

Comment: *Is anything for real*.  Probably *some* things are, which means *yes*.

Comment: Bear Grylls has a behind-the-scenes episode with his camera crew, just FYI.

Comment: Obviously the footage of the plane running out of fuel isn't original, unless there happened to be a camera in the plane at that time. For the other shows, the answers are going to be different.

Comment: How is this too broad? Only one example of a non-fictional show on Discovery channel would be a valid answer!

Comment: We discussed this here: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2748/there-exist-x-claims. You're asking us to examine whether "there exists" anything real on Discovery channel. I think this would get re-opened if you asked us specifically if a particular thing that you're in doubt about is real or not... like some particular thing that Bear did, or some particular mythbusters shot.